# Google sheets query: replacing a value in a cell by appending a list of values

Tags: google-sheets, google-query-language

I have two sheets.

One is an unpivoted sheet with groups and associated IDs(that is persons in this group) like this:

| group | id |
| --- | --- |
| Group1 | ID1 |
| Group2 | ID2 |
| Group2 | ID4 |
| Group3 | ID1 |
| Group3 | ID2 |
| Group3 | ID3 |

The second is rooms and the group with access to that room:

| room1 | room2 | room3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Group1 | Group3 | Group1 |
|  |  | Group2 |

I want to get an output like this using the google query in a new sheet. Where the groups have been replaced by their IDs:

| room1 | room2 | room3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ID1 | ID1 | ID1 |
|  | ID2 | ID2 |
|  | ID3 | ID4 |

My original dataset has over 1000 IDs, 100 groups, and 30 rooms.

Comment: Can you share a copy of your spreadsheet ? That will make it a lot easier to provide a working solution for you.

Comment: @JPV I am sorry, but it has sensitive information that can not be shared, If I get a simple way to do what is described above, I think I would be able to implement it myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sheet 1:

[image]

Sheet 2:

[image]

Sheet 3:

[image]

Formula for cell `A2`:

`=query({Sheet1!$A:$B},"select Col2 where Col1 matches '"&textjoin("|",true,Sheet2!A2:A)&"' ",0)`

Then drag right, eg., cell `B2`:

`=query({Sheet1!$A:$B},"select Col2 where Col1 matches '"&textjoin("|",true,Sheet2!B2:B)&"' ",0)`

Cell `C2`:

`=query({Sheet1!$A:$B},"select Col2 where Col1 matches '"&textjoin("|",true,Sheet2!C2:C)&"' ",0)`